# Expand colour of formatted cell to rest of the row in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have applied conditional formatting to several cells in column A, whereby if I type 'I' this cell will turn grey. What I want to also happen is that colour to expand into column B-I without changing the existing text.

I have seen that you can do this with values by using *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*. However, I am not sure how to apply this as a rule for my format, as the cell doesn't contain a numeric value.

Essentially, what I want is cells B1 to I1 to equal the formula i have set in A1 once I have type "I". How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Avril,**see the snapshots**

Enter this formula `=$A2="L"` , and then applies it to the range which you need to highlight, in my case it is `=$A$2:$I$3`

[image]

[image]